# Overtaking staging area in egit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

When I prepare a commit in egit's *Git Staging* view, I always diff the files one by one and (in most cases) move them to the staging area as one. Sometimes, I see "Oh, that's just commenting, I'll commit that in an extra commit later" and commit only parts of a changed file.

And quite regularly, I see that a specific change

- has to get committed alone (for clarity)
- has to get committed *before* everything I already moved to staging.

If that is the case, I have to clear the staging area, commit that change alone and start all over. Is there a way to preserve what I already moved to staging, whilst overtaking it with the change that has to get committed earlier?

Comment: In plain (non-java non-eclipse) Git: yes, `git stash`, but I think this is more pain than it is worth. Better to do a quick eyeball scan of the entire diff first and then rearrange. What I actually do in practice is make a new "here's a result that works" branch, commit the whole thing there, then go back and build a "nice" series of commits that work towards that "desired result".

Comment: In vanilla `git`, you can also commit everything already in staging first, then commit your separate change, and then reorder the commits using `git rebase -i`. I think it's a worthwhile investment to learn to use CLI git if you haven't already learned it.

Comment: @torek, that "do a quick eyeball scan of the entire diff first" is in fact a nice idea I haven't thought of yet.

Comment: @merlin2011: Rebasing would only work right if the changes were independent, right? (I can get along with the git CLI, but I like to have a nice diff view as in eGit)

Comment: Yes, but if you started with an entire set of changes and then committed separate parts, I don't see how the changes could be not independent. That is,  if you initially could have committed in either order,  then the commits should be safely reorderable.

Comment: You can do that in Eclipse too. There is very nice interface for interactive rebase where you can reorder, edit, squash and reword commits. You can find that option in history view in context menu of previous commits.

Comment: Just tried it and it worked very nicely. But to be honest, I always shy away from "dangerous stuff" like rebasing.